# How to send key-value pair and binary information together to the server using Python

Tags: php, python, post, server, python-requests

The process is I send a ticket to the server, the server will respond with information I need. For example,

```
import requests
URL = "https://ssl.XXX.com/sql_v5i.php"
Ticket = {"A":"1","B":"2"}  # a dictionary
ticket_post = requests.post(URL, data=Ticket)
print ticket__post.text
```

But how to send the the Ticket with `"A":"1", "B":"2"` and binary data (with only data and no key) all at once ?

To comolete this task, there is piece of php works:

```
<?php

$BASE_SERVER_URL="https://ssl.XXX.com/sql_v5i.php"
$TICKET = array(
          'fn' => 'ticket',
          'testid' => '2'
          ... # And many other key-value pair in the TICKET array
          );    

class DataStreamer{
  private $data;
  private $pos;

function __construct($data) {
  $this->data = $data;
  $this->pos = 0;
}

function stream_function($handle, $fd, $count){
$res = substr($this->data, $this->pos, $count);
$this->pos += strlen($res);
return $res;
}
}

function sendTicketToServer($data) {
global $TICKET, $BASE_SERVER_URL; # TICKET is an array stores ticket           
                                  #  information in php
$ret = array(true);  
$postFields = "";
foreach ($TICKET as $name => $val)
    $postFields = (empty($postFields) ? "" :  "${postFields}&") ."${name}=" . urlencode($val); 

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );  
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "${BASE_SERVER_URL}?" . $postFields );  
                                        # add key-value pairs
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );

 if (!empty($data)) { # data is the binary string , add binary string
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/octet-stream', 'Content-length: ' . strlen($data))); 
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, array(new DataStreamer($data), "stream_function")); 
    } else {
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/octet-stream', 'Content-length: 0')); 
}

$resp = curl_exec($ch);
$code=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if( $resp === FALSE || $code !== 200 ) {
    echo "!!!!! Failed to get connection from the server. Code:    $code\n";
    return array(ERR_NO_SERVER_CONNECTION."000");
}

curl_close($ch); 
return $ret;
```

How to do the same this in Python (using Requests or not are both acceptable).

The binary_data = "����5UU��ǚ���������h�V�����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������"

Comment: Is _Pyghon_ a library of some sort?

Comment: `PHP` doesn't send `Ticket` as POST data but in url - see `"${BASE_SERVER_URL}?" . $postFields`  - so it uses url `https://ssl.XXX.com/sql_v5i.php?A=1&B=2`. You can use `params=Ticket` in `requests` to do the same. And then you can us `data=` to send binary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` example doesn't send `Ticket` as `POST` data but as `GET` data - it means in url

```
https://ssl.XXX.com/sql_v5i.php?A=1&B=2
```

You can use `params=Ticket` to do the same in `requests`. And then you can use `data=` or `files=` to send binary data.

I use special portal [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org) to test request but your portal may need more work.

```
import requests

url = "http://httpbin.org/post"
ticket = {"A":"1","B":"2"}
binary_data = b'hello world'

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
}

r = requests.post(url, params=ticket, data=binary_data, headers=headers)

print('--- requests ---')
print(r.url)
print(r.request.headers)
print(r.request.body)

print('--- response ---')
print(r.text)
```

Result:

```
--- requests ---
http://httpbin.org/post?B=2&A=1
{'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Length': '11', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.12.1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': '*/*'}
b'hello world'
--- response ---
{
  "args": {
    "A": "1", 
    "B": "2"
  }, 
  "data": "hello world", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "11", 
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.12.1"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?B=2&A=1"
}
```

---

You can also use local proxy server (ie. [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)) to compare PHP request with Python request.

PHP:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
```

Python:

```
proxy = {
    'http': '127.0.0.1:8888',
    'https': '127.0.0.1:8888',
}

r = requests.post(url, params=ticket, data=binary_data, 
                    headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot. In the example, binary_data = b'hello world'. But in my case, binary_data = "����5UU��ǚ���������h�V�������������������........������������������������������"  (It is too long to put it all in the comment section). When I run the code, it shows "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xef' in the file on line X (binary string line), but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details ". How should I send the this "binary data" to the server ?